# TensorFlow: How to get dtype of placeholder?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

Is there a way to get the `dtpye` of a placeholder in a similar fashion to `ph.get_shape()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ph.dtype. It return data type of the placeholder.

```
    import tensorflow as tf 
    X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name="X") 
    print(X.dtype) # >> <dtype: 'float32'>
```